# Nothing happened after updating data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There is nothing changed when I'm updating my record. Before this I don't put $id in the function but after make some research, I need to put it and also put in the route. Still, I do not have any idea know where is my mistakes.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/administrator','AdminController@index');
Route::post('/admin/create','AdminController@create');
Route::get('/admin/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edit');
Route::post('/admin/{id}/update', 'AdminController@update');
Route::post('/admin/delete', 'AdminController@destroy');
```

**AdminController**

```
public function edit($id) {
   $admin = Admin::find($id);
   return view('admins.edit',['admins'=>$admin]);
  }

public function update(Request $request, $id) {
   $admins = Admin::find($id);
   $admins->name = $request->name;
   $admins->branch = $request->branch;
   $admins->email = $request->email;
          
   if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){
      $filename = $request->avatar->getClientOriginalName();
      $request->avatar->storeAs('images/'.$request->email,$filename,'public');
      $admins->avatar = $request->email.'/'.$filename;
  }
else
{
   $admins->avatar='default.png';
}
$admins->save();

return redirect('/administrator')->with('success','Your details are updated!');
```

**profile.blade.php**

```
<h4 class="heading"><b><center>Admin's Details</center></b></h4>
<ul class="list-unstyled list-justify"><center>
    <li><b>ID: </b>{{$admins->id}}</li>
    <li><b>Name: </b>{{$admins->name}}</li>
    <li><b>Branch: </b>{{$admins->branch}}</li>
    <li><b>Email: </b>{{$admins->email}}</li></center>
</ul>
<div class="text-center"><a href="/admin/{{$admins->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Profile</a></div>
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form action="/admin/{id}/update" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div>
  <div class="form-group hidden">
  <label for="id">id</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="{{$admins->id}}"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$admins->name}}"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">Branch</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="branch" value="{{$admins->branch}}" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$admins->email}}"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
  <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control-file" value="{{$admins->avatar}}">
  </div>

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: You can check like this ```dd($admin->wasChanged())``` put before return redirect

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> web.php

```
  Route:: resources ('admin', 'AdminController');
```

> edit.blade.php

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form action="{{route('admin.update',$id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div>
  <div class="form-group hidden">
  <label for="id">id</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="{{$admins->id}}"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$admins->name}}"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">Branch</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="branch" value="{{$admins->branch}}" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$admins->email}}"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
  <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control-file" value="{{$admins->avatar}}">
  </div>

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

> AdminController

```
                public function update(Admin $admin, Request $request)
                {
                    $admin->update([$this->requestValidate($request)]);
                    $this->storeImage($admin);
                    return redirect(route('admin.index'));
                }

                public function requestValidate($request)
                {
                    return $request->validator([
                        'name' => 'string | required',
                        'branch' => 'string |required',
                        'email' => 'string | required | email'
                    ]);
                }

                public function storeImage($request)
                {
                    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
                        $filename = $request->avatar- 
                                 >getClientOriginalName();
                        $request->avatar->storeAs('images/' . $request- 
                            >email, $filename, 'public');
                        $request->avatar = $request->email . '/' . $filename;
                    } else {
                        $request->avatar = 'default.png';
                    }
                }
```

> Use this stardant with validate maybes it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

add `name()` to route then call in view

```php
Route::post('/admin/{id}/update', 'AdminController@update')->name('admin.update');
```

in blade

```php
<form action="{{route('admin.update',$admins->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: @IrdinaZulkeflee that is validation error u need to print in from